# Html5 canvas how do I know when it finishes rendering

Tags: html, canvas

excuse my English.
drawing if more figures and pictures on canvas.
how do I know when he finished doing the rendering?
thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the canvas will always be immediately modified by the results of your drawing commands. As JS is single-threaded, your next line of JS code will not execute until your changes have been committed.

Here is some simple test code:

```js
var c = document.createElement('canvas');
c.width = c.height = 1;
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
console.log( [].join.call( ctx.getImageData(0,0,1,1).data ) );
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,1,1);
console.log( [].join.call( ctx.getImageData(0,0,1,1).data ) );
```

Chrome, Firefox, and IE9 all output:

```js
0,0,0,0
255,0,0,255
```

…showing that the context was changed as soon as I called `fillRect`.

Here's a more robust test:

```
function showBox(){console.log([].join.call(ctx.getImageData(0,0,2,2).data))}
var c = document.createElement('canvas');
c.width = c.height = 1000;
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
showBox();
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,0.02)";
for (var i=1;i<50000;++i) ctx.fillRect(0,0,1000,1000);
showBox();
setTimeout(showBox,2000);
```

With the above, you see this output:

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
255,0,0,230,255,0,0,230,255,0,0,230,255,0,0,230
255,0,0,230,255,0,0,230,255,0,0,230,255,0,0,230
```

However, the first line displays immediately, and the second line is only shown after a pause. The fact that the 2nd and 3rd lines are the same is strong (but circumstantial) evidence that the canvas context's contents change only when you call a 'commit' operation (e.g. stroke/fill), and are immediately available thereafter.